# How to make element below response to the mouse over event when dragging without using Html 5 default draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

All:

I guess this question has been asked before, but I just can not find it.

Right now, what I want to do is:

Make a DIV draggable and when drag it over other draggble DIVs, they can swap position, that is it.

I use D3, but jQuery is OK as well, I have not figure out how to swap, but just the drag part:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
d3.selectAll(".dragitem").on("mousedown.drag", function(){
                            var dragitem  = this;
                            dragitem.startpos = {
                                x: this.offsetLeft,
                                y: this.offsetTop
                            };
                            dragitem.ptrpos = {
                                x: d3.event.clientX,
                                y: d3.event.clientY
                            }
                            var helper = d3.select("body").select("#drag-helper");
                            if(helper.empty()){
                                helper = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("id", "drag-helper");
                            }
                            helper.style({
                                position:"absolute",
                                left: dragitem.startpos.x,
                                top: dragitem.startpos.y,
                                width:"auto",
                                height: "auto"
                            });
                            $(dragitem).clone().appendTo(helper.node());
                            $(dragitem).remove();
                            d3.select(document)
                                .on("mousemove.drag", function(){

                                    helper
                                        .style("cursor", "move");
                                    var diff = {
                                        dx: d3.event.clientX-dragitem.ptrpos.x,
                                        dy: d3.event.clientY-dragitem.ptrpos.y
                                    }
                                    console.log(diff.dx, diff.dy);
                                    helper.style({
                                        left: dragitem.startpos.x+diff.dx,
                                        top: dragitem.startpos.y+diff.dy
                                    });

                                })
                                .on("mouseup.drag", function(){
                                    d3.select("#drag-helper").remove();
                                    d3.selectAll(".dragitem").on("mousedown.drag",null);
                                    d3.select(".layout-ctrl").style("background-color", "gold")
                                    d3.select(document)
                                        .on("mousemove.drag",null)
                                        .on("mouseup.drag", null);
                                })
```

The code above can make DIV response to drag, but when drag element over another  .draggable, **I do not know how to make that DIV response to mouseover**

Thanks